# Android minSDKVersion and targetSDKVerion

Tags: android

I am very new to android. If this is the very basic question . bear with me.

I have set like below in my AndroidMenifest.

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

wont my application run after API level 17 and below API level 11 ?

I am using SDK Platform 17. can i mention targetSDKVersion as 18?

Comment: Ofcourse it will run.Run it in the emulator and test it.

Comment: Search before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your application will run on API level 18 but will not run below API 11. You can set maxSdkVersion using `android:maxSdkVersion="18"`. If you set this then your app will not work on api level 19.